# Why does '&SAMLRequest' get appended to my ADFS entrypoint URL?

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs2.0, passport-saml

I am using adfs IDP and saml for sso using passport-saml.

My entry point is as follows:

```
https://<domain-name>/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx?loginToRp=https://<domain-name>/saml/metadata
```

When I give this URL, the adfs sso login page loads fine, but when I run the application, `&SAMLRequest` gets appended with this URL:

```
https://<domain-name>/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx?loginToRp=https%3A%2F%2F<domain-name>%2Fsaml%2Fmetadata&SAMLRequest=nVNBbtswEPyKwLskS0lQh7BsODaKGkhbw1Z76CVgyJVDgCJV7ipxfl9KtgIfGh18IrA7HM7OLGeLY22iV%2FConS1YlkzYYj5DUZuGL1t6sTv42wJSFGAWed8oWOstdwI1citqQE6S75ffH3meTHjjHTnpDIs264I93cL09uY5z%2FPptMrvIBdimrHo9%2FBguBGAiC1sLJKwFEqT7EucZXGWl%2FmE5xm%2FuUvus%2Fs%2FLNqeqR%2B0VdoexnU8n0DIv5XlNt7%2B3JcsWiKCp%2FDwyllsa%2FB78K9awq%2FdY8FeiBrkaao7IdK4VlXaACbS1SxaBw%2B0FdSLHkGmQlWYGkw3qtlYTVoQqL0%2BWGcTgc1xYdxB29LtmmKMpfM5rYGEEiTYKRDe2%2BQvkhg3QAzDsrlxUpgYjo0HxBgsaXqPtZqlF7xD6j8C0Wa9dUbL92tS%2F%2Bp8LehzdJZkfUWruOqhHGqhzVKpTlzIyBj3tvIQjCsY%2BRZYOkg77yKofjNDhgTHqzZz5epGeI1dmHAUkgaLL4lXJji4g%2Boaw0dhksuOOpS34XhzXnWLDTIMVnphsXGeztH8T8%2F81PvEjo%2Fu5e%2Bd%2FwM%3D&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1&Signature=EdEYkblB2aOEWvoeMtmWVOkeePocMAeRu2gGBRWrjyQvx%2BEP8eekHSb4IQwodJIui%2BXw%2F%2B0ziKD%2FmwFgaIlFhmWa3ZXpiluzhG8OjK2CaH1trnXNrZM3L%2FYANlXwVl2Z4WF4GF8EP7tmIci8XxFrdP%2Fz3EZ2rlCRdELJV%2FK9wNUUiMFF6FLdExcvZieb5ug15I9wynZndhzAZL46f3cjPvMpsJ9oekR8OKIejXmYOevW0OMq%2BbGGipHKE6B1WwTSaPWGrhdEYPSTHvKpmWrz%2F%2FDscCdF9zLqv%2FGY7TgMhTg9FtlfeQ2jnqeaABBilgYaF4B5zLfCGKk5BmxqwzazGg%3D%3D
```

The `&` symbol causes the page to  load with an error, but when I replace this symbol with any other symbol, the page loads fine. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the request is a GET vs a POST.

Comment: That fixed the issue.Thanks!!
Now I am facing another issue, when it redirects after authentication it says request entity is too large and displays an error page.
req.user is undefined.

Comment: Then, mark the answer as correct and ask another question. It is not just for the points but to help other users w/o mixing questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

loginToRp is supposed to be the name of the application but you have set it to metadata?

The point is to avoid asking the user to pick an application because you have already specified it.